# Continuous Functions On Grassmannans under containment restrictions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, grassmannians

Let $V$ be a vector space. Suppose that for a $x\in V$, we are given some subspace of dimension no more than d (e.g., the kernel of some operator defined on V, which varies smoothly with x), call it $\pi(x)$

Are there any known conditions for the existence of a function $\eta$ from $V$ to the grassmannian $Gr(V,d)$ which are continuous/smooth, so that $\eta(x)$ always contains $\pi(x)$ as a subset?

Comment: Hi Miel! If $\pi$ is continuous than you can always lift to a higher Grassmannian (essentially by the fact that $V$ is contractible). There are obvious, very natural counter examples when $\pi$ is merely lower semicontinuous, eg $\pi(v)=\text{span}(v)$. I suppose that if $\pi$ is upper sc then you're OK. In any case, I find your question a bit vague. Could you give more details on the kind of $\pi$ you have in mind?

Comment: Hi Uri! Thanks for the comment. The $\pi$ I have in mind is defined in the following way - I have a smooth function $f:V = \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and I can look at the Hessian matrix $d^2 f(x)$ at any point $x$. I define $\pi(x)$ to be the span of the eigenvectors of $d^2 f(x)$ with non-negative eigenvalues. I believe that this choice of $\pi$ makes it usc.

Comment: Then I would suggest to repost the question asking if such a continuous $\eta$ exists assuming $\pi$ is usc.